# Blueberry bush not looking very lively

Tags: watering, fruits, flowering, blueberries, ph

I have been growing a blueberry bushes and am not sure that I am having much success. The plant doesn't appear to have done much since it was planted and just appears to be slowly loosing leaves and flowers.

Would anyone have any recommendations? maybe the soil is not acidic enough? Maybe the plant is not getting enough water? Is it just not the right time of year? (mid winter to early spring) I also think I might have planted the plant too high up and some of the roots are exposed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Photos** (click to enlarge)

These are photos of the blueberry plant soon after being planted (14th July - Note southern Australian climate):

[image: Blueberry plant]
[image: blueberry plant]

These are photos of the blueberry plant now (10th September) The first one is an overall shot and the second shows the exposed roots, I understand that this is not ideal, but I don't think that it is the main issue:

[image: Blueberry plant]
[image: Exposed blueberry roots]

Comment: You have your soil pH low enough? In the wild, they're not very pick about much else; and even scruffy looking plants can put out a nice crop of berries. I suppose these plants are a *long* ways from northern Minnesota wild-type. Do you have a cultivar name? There might be better info under that.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is a 'Shunshine Blue' blueberry bush. Would you be able to give any more information based on that?

Comment: There's tons out there on this cultivar: https://www.google.com/search?biw=1269&bih=656&q=sunshine+blue+blueberry&oq=sunshine+blue+blueberry&gs_l=psy-ab.3...48204.48472.0.50664.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.P3WvMvBbreg Videos and all. Looks like it's often container grown rather than planted in ground. It may be objecting to the high rhenium (or suchlike) content of of your Australian dirt. Locally grown stock, or sent across the equator? Two consecutive summers might be hard on a plant.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll have a look. I’m pretty sure that it would be locally grown, as I got it from a local nursery, and I haven’t actually owned it for a summer yet, winter just finished, so will have to see. Thanks for your help though and I’ll look into the dirt.